# За идиота ответят. Нужно ли здесь тире?

Tags: пунктуация

За идиота ответят. Тире ведь не нужно?

Comment: типа обзывали-обзывали, и ответят теперь....

Answer (score 2):

Тире, скорее всего, и не нужно.                                                   А вот "идиота" я бы взяла в кавычки. Иначе изменится смысл предложения. Получается, что отвечать будет не сам "идиот", а кто-то вместо него (какие-то неведомые "они"). Предложение  становится неопределённо-личным.

Answer (score 1):

**За идиота ― ответят.**

**Авторское интонационное тире** можно употребить **в заголовках статей**, где говорится о  политиках, которые публично  называли так нового американского президента, пока он не победил на выборах.

Кавычки тогда не нужны, текст понятен.